# Change value to placeholder (input field)

Tags: jquery, replace

I want to change the value attribute to placeholder with jQuery. So the result would be something like this

Original

```
<input type="text" value="Enter name" />
```

What I want to change above to

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" />
```

I have only found solutions for changing the actuall text between the "" and not the text before those. So replaceWith, replaceAll does'nt seems to work.

Someone having an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may use

`.removeAttr('value')` to remove attribute

**Example:**

```
$('input[type=text]').removeAttr('value');
```

and add new attribute with

`.attr('placeholder','Enter name')`

**Example:**

```
$('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder','Enter name');
```

**As suggested by `rcdmk`**

**You may do it chaining the method:**

```
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function() { 
        var $this = $(this); 
        $this.attr("placeholder", $this.attr("value")).removeAttr("value"); 
    });
```

Comment: I would add an answer, but this suits well. Just have to add that you can do it chaining the methods: `$('input[type="text"]').each(function() { var $this = $(this); $this.attr("placeholder", $this.attr("value")).removeAttr("value"); });`

Comment: @rcdmk: Thanks and added in my answer.

Comment: placeholders doesn't work for ie 8 you need to find a fix like jquery placeholder

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" value="enter text...">

var plcehldr = "enter text...";    
$( "#searchInput" ).focusin(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr("value");
});

$( "#searchInput" ).focusout(function() {
   $(this).attr("value",plcehldr);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/2qutf/14/